# MSAL for Java quickstart sample app throws exception

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have recently started studying MSAL. When I run the Java sample from the link below, I get redirected to an error screen and the authentication does not work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-java-webapp#register-and-download-your-quickstart-app

What I have done is the following. Is there any problem with this approach?

- Create AAD
- Downloaded the sample program from the Quick Start section of the instructions.
- Created a war from "msal-java-webapp-sample" by maven, put to webapp under tomcat folder, and run it.

I followed the errors and found that
*AuthHelper#getAuthResultByAuthCode(l.195)* throws an exception, but I have no idea why it is happening.

If you can give me a hint, I would appreciate it.

Thank you for reading my poor English.

Comment: I've added some of the configurations, pls feel free to share your further problems if exists.

Comment: @Tiny-wa Thank you for your answer with capture! I'll challenge again, and if not, reply again. I challenge on tomcat with war, but not do on eclipse.

Comment: Is there any progress? If you feel my post is helpful, you can mark it as the answer so that it may help others :).

Comment: I suppose same problem as I experienced. Answer in my question. [msal-java-webapp-sample does not work when deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441167/msal-java-webapp-sample-does-not-work-when-deployed-to-tomcat/73441168#73441168)

Comment: I suppose same problem as I had [msal-java-webapp-sample does not work when deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441167/msal-java-webapp-sample-does-not-work-when-deployed-to-tomcat/73441168#73441168)

Answer (score 0):

I aslo used the sample to learn about java msal.

This is a springboot application, so when I tried this sample, I opened it with eclipse, so that's true I skip the steps of packaging the project with maven. Let's say some configuration steps. Here's a doc with details, you can also [followed it](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample).

[image]
[image]
[image]

This sample showed us how to use filter to catch all the income requests and check if it has authorized, and decide if allow the request to access your api. See AuthFilter.java for details.