# msal-java-webapp-sample does not work when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal

I suppose same problem as described in question [MSAL for Java quickstart sample app throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762029/msal-for-java-quickstart-sample-app-throws-exception). When using IDE and deploying to embedded tomcat, app works. After spending one day, I figured out what is the problem.
Application `AuthPageController` specifies `@RequestMapping("/msal4jsample/secure/aad")`. This works with embedded tomcat. When deployed to tomcat server, tomcat removes application name from path since it is deployment information and exploded folder name depends on war file name. Same application can be deployed multiple times to different folders. Tomcat maps url as `/secure/aad` and request in this case is never handled. To fix problem, I created array of request mappings `@RequestMapping(value = {"/msal4jsample/secure/aad", "/secure/aad"})`.
I forked MS Azure repository and made changes. Please take a look at [zdenko-s/ms-identity-java-webapp](https://github.com/zdenko-s/ms-identity-java-webapp)
There are other fixes too.

- War file name is specified in pom.xml, no need to rename it. Removed rename step from documentation also
- .gitignore wrongly specifies exclude `target`. Should be `*/target`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing info. Fix in my forked branch